# LESS loop for array data-name's

Tags: loops, less

the following works as intended:

```css
span[data-name='first']::after, span[data-name='second']::after,  {
  content: " ⭐️";
}
```

However, I want to create a loop so I can just add it to a list of `favourites`:

```css
@favourites:
  'first',
  'second'
;

.createfavourites(@i:1) when(@i <= length(@favourites)) {
    @name: extract(extract(@favourites, @i),1);
    .span[data-name=@{name}]::after {
      content: " ⭐️";;
    }
    .createfavourites(@i + 1);
}
.createfavourites();
```

I'm new to less and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I read the [Loop](https://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) docs, and I think this should work...

I cannot use any @imports.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following for anyone interested:

```css
// mixin to iterate over colors and create CSS class for each one
.createfavourites(@i: length(@favourites)) when (@i > 0) {
    .createfavourites(@i - 1);
    @name: extract(@favourites, @i);
    span[data-name=@{name}]::after {
        content: " ⭐️";
    }
}

.createfavourites(); // run the mixin
```